# error 5 : the database has been placed in a state ..... prevents it from being opened or locked

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

There are two different applications with different functions and each one of them are updating the database, but the problem is when the first one tries to update the database it gets interrupted by the second and the opposite. Its a multi-user environment , i assume splitting the database its a good option but is there something else to do? and if someone could help me with splitting part if there's no other option?

please help and thank you.

Comment: This is *one* reason why Access is a bad idea for multi user environments.

Comment: @MattWilko - If they haven't split the database then they deployed it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can lock table before the process want to operate the database. Then unlock it after complete operation.

```
LOCK TABLES t1 READ;
select * from t1;
Unlock TABLES t1;
```